# How can I get access to and display an offline english dictionary in my android app?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, offlineapps

I'm currently building a vocabulary Android mobile app, and I want to allow the users to be able to look up different words with their definitions on the app.

I was thinking of using a database to manually store each word along with its definition, but I am looking for an easier solution (considering there are 1 million words).

Are there any **built-in classes or libraries** that I can use to import dictionary/words data to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Princeton Wordnet dictionary (details at http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

A Java API to interface to this dictionary can be found at http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Seems like the resource I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I already did this to my dictionaries:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=e-Biene%20DEV&hl=en

You can make conversion to your simple database, tblLanguage1[word, translation] tblLanguage2[word, translation]

to (SQLite format [extract it from emulator], and then attach this converted SQLite db with your App offline).

It will be quick and fast for searching.

and Use: DB created in emulator with structure like: 
Tables:

lang1_Content 
lang1_segments 
lang1_segdir

use this instead of simple db.